# Legend title alignment

Tags: r, ggplot2

In `ggplot2`, I have a horizontal continuous color legend.  I can only get the legend title (here, **`V3`**) to display to the left of the legend. How can I get the legend title to display *above* the legend color bar?

```
d <- as.data.frame(replicate(3, rnorm(100)))
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=V1,y=V2, color=V3)) + geom_point() + 
theme(
    legend.direction="horizontal",
        legend.box="vertical",
        legend.position=c(1,0), 
    legend.justification=c(1,0)
)
```

[image]

Comment: This link may be useful. http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/guide_legend.html

Answer (score 0):

Jazzurro's comment pointed me in the right direction--thanks, I was trying to accomplish what I wanted this using `theme`, and none of the legend options there change title orientation.

I still don't understand why this setting would be in `guide_colourbar` rather than in `theme`, but I guess I'd have to ask Hadley.

```
d <- as.data.frame(replicate(3, rnorm(100)))
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=V1,y=V2, color=V3)) + geom_point() + 
scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("black","white"), 
guide=guide_colourbar(title.position="top"))+
theme(
    legend.direction="horizontal",
        legend.box="vertical",
        legend.position=c(1,0), 
    legend.justification=c(1,0)
)
```